# leafletJS market circle, is there event drag resize radius

Tags: leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I read document and don't find instruction about drag to resize circle of CircleMarker or Circle. Is the library support for that purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can use [Leaflet.Draw](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html) to create and edit layers